# Error creating CPQ - SBQQ__QuoteLine__c Object

Tags: dml, cpq, steelbrick

I am trying to test a controller that I have written which queries SBQQ__QuoteLine__c objects. I am running into an error which is preventing me from inserting the object during the @TestSetup method.

I believe it is because I am missing a field on the SBQQ__QuoteLine__c object, but I cannot figure it out because I am unable to see the code in the managed package. Has anyone run into this before?

**Error**

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first
>   error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, SBQQ.QuoteLineAfter:
>   execution of AfterInsert
>
> caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null
>   object
>
> Class.SBQQ.QuoteLineVO.getCostScheduleId: line 1729, column 1
>   Class.SBQQ.QuoteVO.getDiscountScheduleIds: line 251, column 1
>   Class.SBQQ.QuoteCalculator.initDiscountSchedules: line 83, column 1
>   Class.SBQQ.QuoteCalculator.: line 47, column 1
>   Class.SBQQ.QuoteCalculatorFactory.newQuoteCalculator: line 33, column
>   1 Class.SBQQ.QuoteCalculatorFactory.newQuoteCalculator: line 26,
>   column 1 Class.SBQQ.QuoteService.calculate: line 324, column 1
>   Class.SBQQ.QuoteService.calculate: line 261, column 1
>   Class.SBQQ.QuoteService.calculate: line 257, column 1
>   Class.SBQQ.QuoteService.calculateAndSynch: line 204, column 1
>   Class.SBQQ.QuoteService.processLineTriggerAfter: line 1158, column 1
>   Trigger.SBQQ.QuoteLineAfter: line 12, column 1: []

**Test Class**

The 'insert' on the quote lines objects is what is throwing the error listed above.

```
@isTest 
private class QuoteLineListCtrl_Test {

    private static Integer QUOTE_LINE_ITEM_COUNT = 50;

    @TestSetup
    private static void setup(){
        Account account = (Account) SmartFactory.createSObject('Account');
        insert account;

        Contact contact = (Contact) SmartFactory.createSObject('Contact');
        insert contact;

        Id pricebookId = Test.getStandardPricebookId();

        Opportunity opportunity = (Opportunity) SmartFactory.createSObject('Opportunity');
        opportunity.AccountId = account.Id;
        insert opportunity;

        opportunity.Pricebook2Id = pricebookId;
        update opportunity;

        Product2 product = (Product2) SmartFactory.createSObject('Product2');
        insert product;

        SBQQ__Cost__c cost = new SBQQ__Cost__c();
        cost.SBQQ__Product__c = product.Id;
        cost.SBQQ__UnitCost__c = 100;
        insert cost;

        PricebookEntry pricebookEntry = new PricebookEntry();
        pricebookEntry.Pricebook2Id = pricebookId;
        pricebookEntry.Product2Id = product.Id;
        pricebookEntry.IsActive = true;
        pricebookEntry.UnitPrice = 100;
        insert pricebookEntry;

        SBQQ__Quote__c quote = new SBQQ__Quote__c();
        quote.SBQQ__Account__c = account.Id;
        quote.SBQQ__Opportunity2__c = opportunity.Id;
        quote.SBQQ__PrimaryContact__c = contact.Id;
        quote.SBQQ__Primary__c = TRUE;
        quote.Final_Signature_Date__c = Date.today();
        insert quote;

        List<SBQQ__QuoteLine__c> quoteLineItems = new List<SBQQ__QuoteLine__c>();
        for(Integer i = 0; i < QUOTE_LINE_ITEM_COUNT; i++){
            SBQQ__QuoteLine__c quoteLineItem = new SBQQ__QuoteLine__c();
            quoteLineItem.SBQQ__Quote__c = quote.Id;
            quoteLineItem.SBQQ__Quantity__c = 1;
            quoteLineItem.SBQQ__RegularPrice__c = 100;
            quoteLineItem.SBQQ__CustomerPrice__c = 50;
            quoteLineItem.SBQQ__Cost__c = cost.Id;

            quoteLineItems.add(quoteLineItem);
        }

        insert quoteLineItems;
    }

    @isTest
    private static void queryQuoteLines() {

        SBQQ__Quote__c quote = [SELECT Id FROM SBQQ__Quote__c LIMIT 1];

        Test.startTest();

            List<SBQQ__QuoteLine__c> quoteLineItems = QuoteLineListCtrl.queryQuoteLines(quote.Id);

        Test.stopTest();

        System.assertEquals(null, quoteLineItems);
        System.assertEquals(QUOTE_LINE_ITEM_COUNT, quoteLineItems.size());
    }
}
```

Comment: The `insert` line in your trigger is not what's causing this error. The error is caused by a `NullPointerException` seven levels deep in your stack trace. You need to figure out what's going on at `SBQQ.QuoteLineVO.getCostScheduleId()`, line 1729.

Comment: I agree. I have been trying to create a 'Cost' object, but I am just grasping as straws here. It is definitely because I am missing some type of relationship which is needed later down the line by other code.

Comment: (Rephrasing to note that it's a managed package). Most likely, your test code inserts data that does not fulfill some invariant the code expects, and it fails to guard against it. We can't tell without seeing it what that might be. You'll likely need to go to the package developers/documentation.

Answer (score 2):

If you didn't figure this out yet, you need to add the SBQQ__Product__c lookup field value to your quote line.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be related to "insert or update" DML on [after insert] of the Quote Line trigger.
As I know, Trigger can not run insert or update dml in after insert Trigger.
So try running it before trigger.
I hope this helps.